# Excel VBA macro works randomly

Tags: excel, vba

i need some advice regarding this macro.

This macro cuts and copies from "LATURAP" sheet, rows if specific conditions are met. exmpl. starts with number 170889 and so on.

Problem is that, when i run this macro, it will only works once when i have imported this to excel.

Can somebody explain what i'm missing here?

```
Sub Laturap()

    Dim i As Integer

    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.DisplayStatusBar = False
    Application.EnableEvents = False

    a = Worksheets("LATURAP").Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

    For i = 3 To a

                                           'selection from LATURAP to 1708

                                         If Left(Range("A" & i), 6) = 170889 
  Then


   Worksheets("LATURAP").Range("A:J").Rows(i).Cut


    Worksheets("1708").Activate

                b = Worksheets("1708").Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

                                Worksheets("1708").Cells(b + 1, 1).Select

                                              Worksheets("1708").Paste

                                     Worksheets("LATURAP").Activate

.........
```

Comment: End If
                                     
                                     
                                     Next i
                                    
                                     
                                     
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Application.DisplayStatusBar = True
    Application.EnableEvents = True
    
End Sub

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try this(comments added in code)...

```
Sub Laturap()
Dim ws1 As Worksheet, ws2 As Worksheet, i As Long

Set ws1 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("LATURAP")
Set ws2 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("1708")
x = 1

    With ws1 'wrap your code in the worksheet variable
        For i = 3 To .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row 'you can assign the last row as a variable and use it, this cuts down the lines of code
            If Left(.Range("A" & i), 6) = 170889 Then 'check the first 6 characters in each cell in Col A for the value
                With .Range("A" & i).Resize(, 10) 'if a match select the range in the row from Col A to Col J using resize.
                    .Copy Destination:=ws2.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(x, 1) 'copy the range pan paste to the first cell in ColB in ws2
                    .Clear 'clear the range in ws1
                    x = x + 1 'increases 1 to paste to the next empty row, must be within the If statement
                End With
            End If
        Next i
    End With

Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Application.DisplayStatusBar = True
Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

Comment: Hi,thanks a lot:) It's working, but how can i set destination to Col_A?

Comment: @Kaspar yes just remove the `, 1` from the `.Offset(x, 1)` you should stay on Col A.